# What kind of adjective is long?

Tags: adjectives

I have been wondering what type of adjective *long* is, **quantity** or **quality**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a qualitative adjective:

> [Qualitative adjectives](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/qualitative-and-classifying-adjectives) describe the qualities of a person or thing – whether they are large or small, happy or sad, etc. ***This type of adjective is gradable.***

For example:

> - a fairly tall man
> - a very boring film
> - a really long holiday
> - an extremely expensive car

(ODO)

A [quantitative adjective](https://www.learngrammar.net/a/examples-of-quantitative-adjective) modifies a noun by indicating a number/quantity It can be either cardinal or ordinal number.